# Update fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, updates, android-listfragment, android-fragmentactivity

say I have a few fragments displaying and doing certain things. Now, based on some event, I want to change the screen(or content) for a fragment. 
[EDIT]

For example.

My first layout, layout A, has a listview. And another layout, layout B has a table view. I am currently displaying the layout A in the fragment. On list item click, I want to display layout B in the same fragment.

How is this done?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very broad and general question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I have edited the question to include more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly this is how I would go about it.

I assume you have created fragment classes for your list fragment (fragment A) and view fragment (fragment B).

We can use the fragmentManager to be able to swap out fragments in the layout view.

```
//grab fragmentManager, this will allow us to switch out fragments
FragmentManager fragManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();

//first remove the current fragment
fragTransaction.remove(fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.layout_view));

//replace the current FragmentA with FragmentB
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_view, new FragmentB());

//add to backstack if you want the android back button to work properly
fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

//and lastly, we commit the changes to the fragmentManger's transaction
fragTransaction.commit();
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Will replacing the fragment ensure that the new fragment takes up the same screen space as the previous fragment or does that depend on the layout?

Comment: @Namratha there are a couple different ways it can take up the full screen space as the previous. Depending on your intial layout where you have the <fragment /> tag and what the width/height is set on that as well as the layouts inside of your FragmentA or FragmentB will determine the layout size and if it fills the entire screen.

Comment: I see. Thanks. My fragment B would be declared in the same xml file as Fragment A right? So, how would the application know which fragment to display?

Comment: I tried the method you suggested. The fragment B displays right on top of fragment A. So I can see a jumbled mess. How come the previous fragment is not removed even after remove and replace calls?

Comment: No, FragmentA and FragmentB would have different xml files as well as different Fragment class files. Be sure to use fragmentTransaction.remove() with dynamically created Fragments not fragments within the same xml file.

Answer (score 1):

> My first layout, layout A, has a listview. And another layout, layout
>   B has a table view. I am currently displaying the layout A in the
>   fragment. On list item click, I want to display layout B in the same
>   fragment.
>
> How is this done?

You could use the new nested fragments API(available through the compatibility package and with normal fragments API 16+). Instead of the current `Fragment` that holds a `ListView`(and which you'll replace by a table), you'll have a wrapper `Fragment`, one that has as its view a single `FrameLayout` for its content.

You'll then create two fragments one containing the `ListView` and containing the table layout. Initially you'll add the list based fragment to the wrapper fragment to obtain the start layout and on the item click event you'll use the `getChildFragmentManager()` to replace the list based fragment with the table based fragment(all in the wrapper fragment).